# SQL Server - How to find out who deleted a key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wondering if there a log/audit table for holding info like which users have created/changed/deleted keys or indexes etc?

Comment: 2 seconds with Google.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx

Comment: If you already turned on DDL triggers you can check that. Assuming you haven't your next step it to use some kind of transaction log reader

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Thx. Have you come across any good log readers?  I tried ApexSQL Log, but its returning blank result to me.

Comment: No I've never used one before sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The default trace captures DDL changes.  Below is an example to glean some of this information.

```
--Object:Created and Object:Altered events from default trace
SELECT 
     te.name AS EventName
    ,tt.StartTime as st
    ,tt.DatabaseName
    ,tt.ObjectName
FROM sys.traces AS t
CROSS APPLY [fn_trace_gettable](t.path, DEFAULT) AS tt
JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON
    te.trace_event_id = tt.EventClass
WHERE 
    tt.EventClass in (46,164)
    AND tt.EventSubClass = 0
ORDER BY st DESC;
```